# Hibernate: Unable to view Persisted data in MYSQL in between process

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am not hardcore Hibernate Programmer.

Create a native query return bulk data million records:

```
return super.em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Fetching data and build Objects which is persisted using DAO in Loop which have 1 million persists.

```
persist(object)
```

When simultaneously I run select query on table it shows me 0 Results.

```
Select count(*) from Audit_Log;
```

After all records are inserted successfully, MySQL shows me result.

Earlier I was named query for fetching values from DAO and it worked well. Now I opted native query and got this behavior. Is there something I need to change?

Code:

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T, PK> implements GenericDao<T, PK>     {
     @Override
 public T create(final T t) {
  this.em.persist(t);
  return t;
 }

 @Override
 public void flush() {
  org.hibernate.Session session = (org.hibernate.Session)em.getDelegate();
  session.flush();

 }
```

DAO:

```
  @Override
  public Person create(Person person) {
    return (Person) create((MainRecord) person);
  }
```

Comment: show the entire code and the data flow, it isn't clear.IMP, when you persist maybe you just forgot to flush.

Comment: @DemonColdmist: Added code. We are calling DAO method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you persisting 10L (a.k.a. 1M) records in single transaction? Looks like this is this case. Now since TX is open for considerably very long period of time, firing a query on TOAD (or any other SQL client) won't return it since data isn't committed in the DB yet.

Try flushing the data in between.

Also, I hope you're using batching on hibernate as well as driver level. There is no way I will persist 1M records w/o batching.

Comment: Just now i inserted single record and found it did not persist if exception is thrown in between. Due to no persistance; it says Detatched Entity error

Comment: Looks like there are multiple issues here. Obviously it won't persist if there was some error in between and it will become 'detached' since session is closed and object is left behind dangling around. You should be able to persist at least one object before moving to 1m.

Comment: As per your suggestion -> I am using this now ---- > @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public Person createWithReadUncommitedIsolation(Person per) {
      this.em.persist(per);
      this.em.flush();
      return per;
    } < --- and trying to execute

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to try is to use method **flush** or close the session directy while the persist was done.

And the explain was here:

> persist() makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does not guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time. persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries. This is useful in long-running conversations with an extended Session/persistence context.

Comment: Thanks. 
Will it not create issue. Close open / open close again and again. Like in Loop i cant do this multiple times. There are multiple tables in picture which is updating in loop.

Comment: why u do this *Close open / open close again and again*? Well, even u do like that, you can just flush the session out of the loop.

Comment: Actually it is loop for 1 person we are adding multiple things like its relatives its accounts etc in loop. If a person is added, will flush and add account info. Then again other person added and will flush and other info

Comment: The import thing you should know is that the session is created to CRUD no matter how much data you had operated.What's more, you should add transaction in your code.So firstly, you should make sense of the Session.

Comment: I am using this now ---- > @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) public Person createWithReadUncommitedIsolation(Person per) { this.em.persist(per); this.em.flush(); return per; } < --- and trying to execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121582/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-demon-coldmist).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet, it was was similar to approach we using in JDBC batching..

```
             public Long save(HttpServletRequest request) {

//Further business logic here....
for ( int i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
                     getEntityManager().persist((ABC) model);

            if ( i > 0 && i % 2500== 0 ) {
                               getEntityManager().flush();
                               getEntityManager().clear();
                          }
                  }
                     tx.commit();
                   ((EntityManager) session).close();
    }
```